# I have a problem declaring my variables in my program in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that asks for three numbers and then says which is the major number, the minor number and the middle number. When I execute the program, nothing appears in the spaces of major, minor and middle. I don't know if I'm making a mistake declaring my variables or something else.

This is a small part of the code. I didn't post the complete one because it's the same but with the other possibilities.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int N1, N2, N3;
int main()
{
    cout << "First Number: ";
    cin >> N1;
    cout << "\nSecong Number: ";
    cin >> N2;
    cout << "\nThird Number: ";
    cin >> N3;

    if (N1 > N2 && N2 > N3) {
        cout << "\n Major: ", N1;
        cout << "\n Middle: ", N2;
        cout << "\n Minor\n: ", N3;
    }
    else if (N1 > N3 && N3 > N2) {
        cout << "\nMajor: ", N1;
        cout << "\nMiddle: ", N3;
        cout << "\nMinor\n: ", N2;
    }
    // additional cases omitted
}
```

Comment: @TonyTannous "I didn't post the complete one because it's the same but with the other possibilities."

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
cout << "\n Major: ", N1;
```

is, due to [C++ operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), parsed as:

```
(cout << "\n Major: "), N1;
```

The [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) evaluates its left-hand side, discards the result, then evaluates the right-hand side, yielding that as the result of the expression, here `N1`.  But nothing is done with that value.

You want to instead print both values by using `<<` instead of `,`:

```
cout << "\n Major: " << N1;
```

This will be parsed as:

```
(cout << "\n Major: ") << N1;
```

The inner expression prints its argument and yields the stream (`cout`) as the result.  The outer expression then does the same.  Thus, the `<<` operator can be chained indefinitely like this:

```
cout << value1 << value2 << value3 << ... << valueN;
```